# Неизменяемый массив в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Можно ли сделать массив такой, чтобы после добавления элемента, его нельзя было бы изменять?
`const a = [1,2,3]` почему-то не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` сейчас поможет только на уровне сборщика или чеккера отловить мутации переменных. Но со стандарта ECMA-262 появилась возможность заморозить объекты: [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) и [Object.seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal), что работает и для массивов.

Для безопасной и кроссбраузерной работы с иммутабельными данными в Javascript хорошо использовать что-то вроде [mori](https://github.com/swannodette/mori) и [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3];
```

Object.defineProperty(a, "length", {writable: false});

Comment: a = [1,2,3]; // Соз­дать мас­сив a с тре­мя эле­мен­та­ми.
Object.defineProperty(a, "length", // Сде­лать свой­ст­во length
 {writable: false}); // дос­туп­ным толь­ко для чте­ния.
a.length = 0; // a не из­ме­нит­ся.

Comment: [editing-help](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)